# Flutter how to get dates from week number

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get dates from week number in flutter. But I dont know how to do it. I got the week number and the days of the week. Now I want to get the dates from the days in this week.

For example:
**week 2 Monday date,
week 2 Tuesday date,
week 2 Friday date**

I have started with this code but I need to solve it in another way.

```
int weeknumber = 2;

//1=monday, 2=tuesday, 5=friday
List<int> weekdays = [1,2,5];

int year = 2023;

int totaldays = weeknumber * 7;
    final extraDuration = Duration(days: totaldays);
    final startDate = DateTime(year);

    final dates = startDate.add(extraDuration);

    print(dates);
```

Here is the output: **2023-01-15 00:00:00.000**

But I want: **2023-01-09, 2023-01-10, 2023-01-13**

What can I do to get these dates?

Comment: what you want as output ?

Comment: you pass integer and get a day of week in string ?

Comment: I want to print the dates of these days as DateTime

Comment: can you share sample output

Comment: 2023-01-15 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

If you want this output
Monday:2023-01-09 00:00:00.000

Tuesday:2023-01-10 00:00:00.000

Friday:2023-01-13 00:00:00.000

you can work on this code

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
void main() {
  int weeknumber = 2;

  //1=monday, 2=tuesday, 5=friday
  List<String> weekdays = ['Monday','Tuesday','Friday'];

    int year = 2023;

    int firstDayOfWeek = (weeknumber-1) * 7;
    final extraDuration = Duration(days: firstDayOfWeek);

    final startDate = DateTime(year);
    
    final dates = startDate.add(extraDuration);
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      var newDate = dates.add(Duration(days: i));
      if(DateFormat('EEEE').format(newDate) == 'Monday')print('Monday:'+newDate.toString());
      else if(DateFormat('EEEE').format(newDate) == 'Tuesday')print('Tuesday:'+newDate.toString());
      else if(DateFormat('EEEE').format(newDate) == 'Friday')print('Friday:'+newDate.toString());
      
    }
    print(dates);
}
```

Comment: This does not work for : int year = 2026;  int weeknumber = 53. Not even for int year = 2024;  int weeknumber = 1;

Answer (score 0):

> I already made a helper method to that in one of my projects you can use it

```
static DateTime getDateOfWeekday(String shortDayName) {
final Map<String, int> dayNumbers = {
  'Sunday': 7,
  'Monday': 1,
  'Tuesday': 2,
  'Wednesday': 3,
  'Thursday': 4,
  'Friday': 5,
  'Saturday': 6,
};

 static  final Map<String, String> dayNames = {
'Sun': 'Sunday',
'Mon': 'Monday',
'Tue': 'Tuesday',
'Wed': 'Wednesday',
'Thu': 'Thursday',
'Fri': 'Friday',
'Sat': 'Saturday',
   };
  String? fullDayName = Constants.dayNames[shortDayName];
if (fullDayName == null) {
  throw ArgumentError('Invalid day name');
}
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
int currentWeekday = now.weekday;
int targetWeekday = dayNumbers[fullDayName] ?? currentWeekday;
int difference = targetWeekday - currentWeekday;
//add this check if you want the week start from today
if (difference < 0) {
  difference += 7;
}
DateTime targetDate = now.add(Duration(days: difference));

return targetDate;
 }
```